# Rails relationship - Model with no primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm facing a problem.

I have three models in this relationship:

Bills

Apportionment

Users

I would like to type something like:

```
@bill.apportionment.users
```

The idea is to have the information of who shares that bill.

I imagine tables with this information(Example)

```
Apportionment 
id | user_id 
1    1 
1    2 
1    3 

Bill 
id | apportionment_id
1    1
```

So if I do

```
@bill.apportionment.users
```

It would return a collection of users 1, 2 and 3

My current model config is something like this:

```
Model User 
has_many :apportionments

Model Bill 
belongs_to :apportionment

Model Apportionment
belongs_to :users
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If apportionment `belongs_to :user` then it only has one user.  You need to modify the relationship so that apportionment `has_many :users`.

However currently a user has many apportionments, so if you want users to have many apportionments and apportionments to have many users then you'll need to create a joining table and use a habtm relationship http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

Comment: Hi. I made exacly what u mean, i made a habtm(has and belongs to many) relationship between Users and Apportionments and worked like a charm! Thankssssss